# Do .net events flow the current ExecutionContext?

Tags: .net, executioncontext

I see some code optimization about suppressing execution context flow almost immediately before a += style .net event registration (C#)

```
        EnsureExecutionContextSuppressed();
        _eventArgs.Completed += OnEventArgsCompleted;
```

Why? Is that because .net events normally flow the current execution context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET events are simply delegate invocations. They behave like method calls. There is zero impact on the execution context.